# jquery autocomplete for dynamically inserted elements with unknown id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

We have autocomplete working on static form:

```
$(function() {
    return $('#bom_part_name_autocomplete').autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: $('#bom_part_name_autocomplete').data('autocomplete-source'),  
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        },
    });
});
```

The autocomplete above fills in the part name when user choose one. Now we would like to add autocomplete to dynamically inserted elements. Here are a few things we need to consider:

1. element id is unknown until after insertion
2. There may be more than one element inserted on the same form.
3. the id for dynamically inserted elements always starts 'bom_' and ends with '_part_name_autocomplete'. autocomplete needs to match id with this type of pattern.
4. The digits in ids are different from element to element. For example, the id for 1st insertion may be `'bom_123456789_part_name_autocomplete'`, 
   the id for 2nd insertion could be `'bom_123456987_part_name_autocomplete'`

None of online examples we found has unknown element ids. Is it possible to do autocomplete on dynamic elements with unknown ID? If it can be done, an example would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: here is the rails code to create element:

```
    def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
      new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
      fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
        render :partial => association.to_s, :locals => {:f => builder, :i_id => 0} 
      end
      link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{j fields}\")")
    end
```

Here is the javascript for add_fields():

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

Comment: How are the new elements inserted? Why can't you just add the autocomplete when the element is created for insertion?

Comment: It is a rails app and new element is generated by fields_for. Not sure how to add the autocomplete when the element is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after your elements are inserted you can do:

```
$('[id^=bom_][id$=_part_name_autocomplete]').each(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({ // ...
})
```

Its easier to just add it on creation though

Comment: @@juvian Not sure how to add autocomplete when the element is created. Updated the post with code for element generating.

Comment: Never used rails, but if that is generated before dom load, adding the code to the dom load should work

Comment: I think we can add autocomplete before dom load. If doing so, what kind of change we need to make with js function of $('[id^=bom_][id$=_part_name_autocomplete]').each(function(){)}?

Comment: Nothing, just put it inside a `$(document).ready({//the code})`

Answer (score 1):

Referencing an element by ID is not the only way to select it.

You can add the autocomplete when you create the element:

```
function create_element(data) {
    var field = $("<input/>")
    field.data('autocomplete-source', data)
    $(field).autocomplete({
        minLength: 1,
        source: $(field).data('autocomplete-source'),  
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        },
    });
    return field
}
```

Comment: I think we can add the autocomplete before dom load.